# Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined in visual studio 2015

Tags: typescript, requirejs, systemjs, typescript2.0, typescript1.8

**Software:** Visual Studio 2015

When i try to run my application i am getting error as below in my chrome console.

**Console Error :-** String.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

**Detailed Error:-** Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });

Code snippet as below

String.ts

```
export function GetName() {

        return "ERahul";
}
```

app.ts

```
import { GetName } from "./String"
module umd {

    class Greeter {
        element: HTMLElement;
        span: HTMLElement;
        timerToken: number;

        constructor(element: HTMLElement) {
            this.element = element;

            this.element.innerHTML +="Name is "+ GetName;
            this.span = document.createElement('span');
            this.element.appendChild(this.span);
            this.span.innerText = new Date().toUTCString();
        }

        start() {
            this.timerToken = setInterval(() => this.span.innerHTML = new Date().toUTCString(), 500);
        }

        stop() {
            clearTimeout(this.timerToken);
        }

    }

    window.onload = () => {
        var el = document.getElementById('content');
        var greeter = new Greeter(el);
        greeter.start();
    };
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "jsx": "react",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/browser",
        "typings/browser.d.ts"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "buildOnSave": false,
    "atom": {
        "rewriteTsconfig": false
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TypeScript HTML App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="String.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TypeScript HTML App</h1>

    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```